# Rails Enum '0' is not a valid incomeType

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ruby on Rails app that handles a users income, decides if it is an allowance or an income and applies the appropriate tax rates. I have included some `enums` to do basic functions as outlined below.

When I go to update from the default I hit the issue '1' is not a valid incomeType.

Below you can see the set up including model, controller and form.

**model :**

```
class Income < ApplicationRecord
  enum incomeType: {income: 0, allowance: 1 }
  enum taxed: {yes: 0, no: 1 }

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**controller:**

```
class IncomesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_income, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /incomes
  # GET /incomes.json
  def index
    @incomes = current_user.incomes.all
  end

  # GET /incomes/1
  # GET /incomes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /incomes/new
  def new
    @income = current_user.incomes.build
  end

  # GET /incomes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /incomes
  # POST /incomes.json
  def create
    @income = current_user.incomes.new(income_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @income.save
        format.html { redirect_to @income, notice: 'Income was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @income }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @income.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /incomes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /incomes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @income.update(income_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @income, notice: 'Income was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @income }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @income.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /incomes/1
  # DELETE /incomes/1.json
  def destroy
    @income.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to incomes_url, notice: 'Income was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_income
      @income = Income.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def income_params
      params.require(:income).permit(:amount, :frequency, :user_id, :incomeType, :country, :taxed)
    end
end
```

**Form :**

```
<%= form_with(model: income, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if income.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(income.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this income from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% income.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :amount %>
    <%= form.text_field :amount, id: :income_amount %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :frequency %>
    <%= form.select :frequency, options_for_select([['Weekly', '52'], ['Fortnightly', '26'], ['Monthly', '12'], ['Bi-Monthly', '6'], ['Annually', '1']]), id: :income_frequency %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :incomeType %>
    <%= form.select :incomeType, options_for_select([['Income', '0'], ['Allowance', '1']]), id: :incomeType %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :taxed %>
    <%= form.select :taxed, options_for_select([['Yes', '0'], ['No', '1']]), id: :taxed %>ra
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hopefully you can point me in the right direct.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HUTd5Bav9eAfWPTFFyqeD69aL4mIgZodIuL1+9eL0zIhN+SjDwAMcD7AzKEuhm6az4iALBSrDUXd/1vVfN77SQ==",
 "income"=>{"amount"=>"102000.0", "frequency"=>"1", "incomeType"=>"0", "taxed"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update Income",
 "id"=>"4f9fc439-4578-487e-bc5d-02cf0cd9aaa3"}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your `enum incomeType` accepts 0 and 1(ints), and you try to pass '0' and '1'(strings). Event your question title says about that. WBR, cap. Obvious

Comment: Why use a enum at all for something which is clearly a boolean? I'm thinking of `enum taxed: {yes: 0, no: 1 }`.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, pity you didnt take the time to answer the question. could have marked you right, but thanks for the obvious comment. Hopefully I will one day reach your level, I also hope that I never think myself so wonderful that I write obvious!

Comment: Hey Max, you should write your suggestion as an answer then people who come across this could utilise your wonderful insight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is because enum needs key not the value and you are sending value not the key so in your case enum is trying to find '0' as one key which is not present. So just change your form slightly

```
<%= form.select :incomeType, options_for_select([['Income', 'income'], ['Allowance', 'allowance']]), id: :incomeType %>
```

PS : change form for taxed as well.
Hope this will help

Comment: I really value that you took the time to answer this with a helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

@Manishh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851936/5783745) is awesome. Just wanted to show a couple of additional ways to display enum options in the form select:

```
<div>
  <%= form.label :status %>
  <%= form.select :status, Post.statuses.keys %>
</div>
```

and

```
<div>
  <%= form.label :status %>
  <%= form.select :status, Post.statuses.keys.map{ |key| [key.humanize, key] }, selected: @post.status || :draft %>
</div>
```

These two examples are both from [this](https://spaquet.medium.com/activerecord-enum-and-activeview-form-f09dca0ea4b0) source.